# Benefits of using a Case statement over an If statement in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi are there any pros / cons relating to the speed that a stored procedure executes when using an IF statement or choosing to use a CASE statement instead?

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of what you are trying to do it is impossible to answer the question.  In stored procedure languages like T-SQL IF and CASE are used for completely different things.  CASE is used within statements and IF is not.

Comment: I agree.  CASE is an expression, and IF controls execution flow.  You'll have to give an example of code where you're trying to decide between the two.  I'm guessing that you're either trying to set a variable, conditionally (use CASE here but not for perf), or you've misunderstood CASE.

Answer (score 2):

I try not to use `IF`s if I can avoid it, because they are non transactional, i.e. you have generally no guarantee that the condition of the `IF` will still be valid inside the `BEGIN... END` block of the `IF`.

I assume that you mean using `CASE` statements inside a SQL `SELECT`, for example. If the usage is meant to avoid an `IF` then, by all means, do it.

The golden rule of SQL is: *let the server figure out HOW to do things, tell the server what you WANT*.

Answer (score 2):

Don't concern yourself with any speed difference between a case and an IF statement. Because you're dealing with a database, the amount of time it takes to write or read from disk is going to dwarf the time it takes the CPU to branch via an IF or Case. You should focus instead on which makes your code more readable and maintainable.